# How to avoid NullPointerException from Flume Log4jAppender?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, log4j2, flume-ng

Context:
We are trying to use Log4jAppender from Flume NG 1.5.0.1 and Log4j 2.0.2 to stream log events from an application to remove FLume agent. Things work fine with the actual application till the remote Flume agent is shutdown. We are encountering NPE which is obviously not handled in Logger's info method.

We want the following two things to work fine:

1. Application should handle unavailability of remote flume agent and reconnect.
2. Application code should be insulated from Log4j appender internals.

Exception:

```
LOCAL COUNTER: 163
log4j:ERROR Flume append() failed.
LOCAL COUNTER: 164
log4j:ERROR RPC client creation failed! NettyAvroRpcClient { host: nyc-devintapp03.activehealth.loc, port: 41414 }: RPC connection error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flume.clients.log4jappender.Log4jAppender.append(Log4jAppender.java:163)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
    at net.ahm.ce.server.App.main(App.java:18)
```

Source:

```
public class App {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            System.out.println("LOCAL COUNTER: " + i);
            logger.info("PID: " + name + " | COUNTER: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(100l);
        }
    }
}
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.flume=org.apache.flume.clients.log4jappender.Log4jAppender
log4j.appender.flume.Hostname=192.168.4.16
log4j.appender.flume.Port=41414
log4j.appender.flume.UnsafeMode=true
log4j.appender.flume.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.flume.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,flume
```

Comment: This is a bug in Flume's Log4jAppender and you cannot avoid it without patching Flume. I'm having a look at the code now to see how could it be fixed.

Comment: Thanks ! We are also exploring org.apache.flume.clients.log4jappender.LoadBalancingLog4jAppender and there if we kill one of the many hosts and bring it back, things don't fail and reconnect in the application as desired.

Comment: The questions is tagged log4j2 and says "...we are using Log4j 2.0.2" but you are using log4j-1.2. You may be aware that Log4j2 includes a Flume Appender. The log4j2 original author is also a PCM member on Apache Flume, so if you have any issues with that combination I recommend asking on the log4j2 user list or raise a Jira ticket on the log4j2 issue tracker.

Comment: i am not sure how you came to the conclusion:  "but you are using log4j-1.2"